# How to add a column in a panda series that contains the exponential of another column in multiprecision?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprecision, gmpy

Considering this panda data frame :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': list(range(-10000, 10001, 1000))})
```

I would like to insert a column (named `exp_x`) that contains the exponential of these numbers.
Multi precision is needed because some numbers are too large or too low. The gmpy2 library is used (For example : `exp(mpfr(5000))` or `exp(mpfr(-5000))`).

What is the shortest method to do that ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: You can do this with `df['exp'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: exp(mpfr(x)))`

Comment: @NickODell. Thanks for answer. lamba function was the solution. If you want you could change your comment to answer.